# Переход по нужному URL с формы

Tags: jquery

Есть

```
<form id="search_form">
<input type="text" id="search_form_input" placeholder="будем искать?" name="name" size="31" />
<input type="submit" id="search_button" onclick="return false;" value="" />
<a id="search_dropdown"></a>
</form>
```

Как сделать, чтобы переходило после нажатия на /search/тут то, что введено/ на jQuery?

Comment: За очки спасибо, но вам бы они больше пригодились.
На будущее, если ответ вам подходит, достаточно плюсануть и принять его.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то типа:

```
$('#search_form').submit(function(){
    location.pathname = '/search/' + encodeURI($('#search_form_input').val());
    return false;
});
```

**UPD:** Только, уберите `onclick="return false;"`. Обработчик `onsubmit` вешается на всю форму, в этом случае обработчик конкретной кнопки не нужен.